# Loop through array and edit string

Tags: javascript

I have this variable:

```
WelcomeText = 'Hi $0! Welcome to $1!';
```

And I am trying to create this function:

```
translate(WelcomeText, 'Daniel', 'Budapest');
```

Which should return this:

```
'Hi Daniel! Welcome to Budapest!'
```

I have tried to make this function which should support unlimited arguments to replace:

```
export const translator = (str, ...args) => {
  let translate = args.map((item, index) => {
    let stringToReplace = '$' + index;
    let result = str.replace(stringToReplace, item);
    return result;
  });

  console.log(translate);
};
```

But that gives me this:

```
["Hi Daniel! Welcome to $1", "Hi $0! Welcome to Budapest"]
```

Not sure how to explain it more than this, but I am out of words so I hope u can understand my problem with above :)

What am I doing wrong here, and what do I need to do to reach my desired result?

Comment: `map` always creates a new array of the same length, but you want to return a string.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use forEach instead

```js
let WelcomeText = 'Hi $0! Welcome to $1!';

const translator = (str, ...args) => {
  args.forEach((item, index) => {
    let stringToReplace = '$' + index;
    str= str.replace(stringToReplace, item);
  });
  console.log(str);
};

translator(WelcomeText, 'Daniel', 'Budapest');
```

Since you're using map in your original code so it returns a new string on every iteration and you endup getting an array of string, where in actual you need to get a string with all `$`(index) instance replaced so you should be using the replaced string on next iteration onwards

Comment: Yes! I will go with this! :D Thank you very much. Works wonderful! Do you have any advice on how to implement a error handling for this function? I was thinking about just comparing the original string with the translated one to see any difference, but is there more I could do?

Comment: @OsgarSchölander always welcome, i am not clearly understanding what exactly error handling means to you as your last statement means you just want to check whether it has changed anything in string or not ( that comes under unit testing of your function as this is most likely due to problem in logic not in syntax ).

Answer (score 2):

You could take a function as replacement parameter and search for the index of the string.

```js
const
    translate = (string, ...items) => string.replace(/\$(\d+)/g, (_, i) => items[i]),
    text = 'Hi $0! Welcome to $1!';


console.log(translate(text, 'Daniel', 'Budapest'));
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` always creates a new array of the same length, but you want to return a string. You could use `reduce` instead with the text as the initial value:

```js
var welcomeText = 'Hi $0! Welcome to $1!';

const translate = (t, ...args) => args.reduce((a, x, i) => a.replace(`$${i}`, x), t);

console.log(translate(welcomeText, 'Daniel', 'Budapest'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) creates an *array*, so each replacement is treated as a separate thing to replace, so first you replace `$0` and leave `$1` but next time you're replacing from the original string and only replace `$1` but leave `$0`.

Since you don't need an array as a result, you can use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to just keep updating the `str` every time:

```js
const translator = (str, ...args) => {
  
  let translate = args.forEach((item, index) => {
    let stringToReplace = '$' + index;
    str = str.replace(stringToReplace, item);
  });

  console.log(str);
};

const WelcomeText = 'Hi $0! Welcome to $1!';

translator(WelcomeText, 'Daniel', 'Budapest');
```

Alternatively, you could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and use the resulting value:

```js
const translator = (str, ...args) => {
  
  let translate = args.reduce((result, item, index) => {
    let stringToReplace = '$' + index;
    return result.replace(stringToReplace, item);
  }, str);

  console.log(translate);
};

const WelcomeText = 'Hi $0! Welcome to $1!';

translator(WelcomeText, 'Daniel', 'Budapest');
```

You can also [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) with a function as a replacer parameter, which will allow you to dynamically determine what the replacement would be:

```js
const translator = (str, ...args) => {
  let translate = str.replace(
    /\$(\d+)/g, //match a pattern that has $ followed by a number, capture the number
    (match, placeholderNumber) => args[placeholderNumber] //replace with corresponding the value from args
  )

  console.log(translate);
};

const WelcomeText = 'Hi $0! Welcome to $1!';

translator(WelcomeText, 'Daniel', 'Budapest');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let name = args[0];
let place = args[1];

let message = 'Hi ${name}, welcome to ${place}`;
```

Comment: Yes, but that is not as dynamic as I need it to be. Therefore my try to loop through it :)

Answer (score 0):

I would pass to translator array of arrays, like this:

```
const welcome = "Hi $0! Welcome to $1!";

const returnString = (str, name, city) =>
  str.replace("$0", name).replace("$1", city);

const translator = (str, arr) => {
  return arr.map(([name, city]) => returnString(str, name, city));
};

console.log(
  translator(welcome, [
    ["John", "NY"],
    ["Sara", "LA"],
    ["Bill", "SF"]
  ])
);
```

output:
 `["Hi John! Welcome to NY!", "Hi Sara! Welcome to LA!", "Hi Bill! Welcome to SF!"]`